# Deployed application URL not working after appending /cmis/json in browser

Tags: java, dms, sap-cloud-platform

I am in process of learning how document management service (document repositories) works in sap cloud platform.

I am following blog linked https://blogs.sap.com/2019/01/17/how-to-handle-attachments-in-sap-cloud-platform-workflow/
I have completed step1, step2. I have created a test repository and creating a sample Proxy bridge Java App. I was able to deploy and start the CMIS Proxy application.
Step3 is to test the deployed URL which is what I need help with.

```
CMISProxyServlet
```

package com.cf.cloud;

import com.sap.ecm.api.AbstractCmisProxyServlet;

public class CMISProxyServlet extends AbstractCmisProxyServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Override
protected boolean supportAtomPubBinding() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean supportBrowserBinding() {
    return true;
}


public CMISProxyServlet() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected String getRepositoryUniqueName() {
    return "MySampleRepository";
}

@Override
// For applications in production, use a secure location to store the secret key.
protected String getRepositoryKey() {
    return "abcdef0123456789";
}
```

}

WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID"  version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All SAP Cloud Platform users</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
            <!-- Use CONFIDENTIAL as transport guarantee to ensure SSL connection (HTTPS) on public deployments
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> -->
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpSecurityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpSecurityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpCachingHeaderFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpCachingHeaderFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpCachingHeaderFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <display-name>CMISProxyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CMISProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sap.ecm.proxy.CMISProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CMISProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cmis/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Proxy</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/cmis/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>EcmDeveloper</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

Application's hello world servlet works. But when I appended the /cmis/json to the app url I got a 404 error.

I'd like to know two things. 
Firstly, is this a correct use case to see if the documents can be stored in SCP Repository?
Secondly, do we have a dedicated workflow in SCP to handle attachments that this blog refers to, can someone please provide a link?

I apologize if my questions are very vague, I am just trying to figure out how DMS works in S4 Hana Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got the CMIS URL correctly as mentioned in the blog.

Another good way to handle this use case is using SAP Document Center which does not require you to deploy the proxy bridge and maintain it.

In addition you get all the extra functionalities of SAP Document Center.

Also as you mentioned an in built integration with SAP DMS.

Please check the details here

https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_Document_Center/Cloud/en-US

https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/23/connecting-plm-dms-to-sap-document-center/

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really liked the SAP Document Center route. But unfortunately it did not answer my question.